# document.getElementByID('name') возвращает мне null

Tags: javascript

При подключении внешнего скрипта столкнулся с проблемой:

```
var forma = document.getElementById("regform");
validation(forma);
```

Обычная довольно запись возвращает мне null, не пойму почему. Подключение скрипта:

```
  <DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Лабораторная работа 3</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lab3css.css">
    <script src="task1.js" async></script>
</head>
```

И так же сама форма,которую я пытаюсь скопировать в переменную.

```
<form  method="post" id="regform">
```

JS только начал учить,так что извиняюсь, если это очевидно решается.

Comment: В вашем конкретном случае, если вам не нужно слушать событие `load`, нужно убрать `async` из тега `script`.
Однако Вам следует знать, что все же лучше обернуть все в основной слушатель `load` и из него объявить новый слушатель `click`.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var forma = document.getElementById("regform");
  validation(forma);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Код выполняется до создания HTML.

Comment: То есть,подключить его в конец файла ?

Comment: обернуть код в `window.onload = function(){/*код*/}`

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста,а как организовать работу скрипта только по срабатывании события onclick ? Только организовать именно во внешнем скрипте,а не в теге input.

Comment: наилучший вариант `document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("click", function(){/*code*/})`